# Subtract numbers from the results of an SQL query

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio

So what the title says.

My results look like these [100, 200, 300], i have multiple of these, around 2000.

From each one i want to subtract [50, 50, 50], so that the results would be something like [50, 150, 250] and so on and so on.

I guess it is easy for most people, but i cannot find any example and i could not do it myself. how can i subtract a specific number from a query.

My sql uses [ST_AsGeoJSON](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html), something like:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(geom, 32633)) FROM "database";
```

being read via:

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
      // ...
      resultTable[col].Add(reader[col].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the question here?

Comment: ... and what have you tried?

Comment: So, you want to do that on the application level (in c#) or on the database level (in sql)? If it's the first, what datatype is your results stored in? Is that a DataTable, or another collection of some sort?

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear". An "SQL query" is not something you can subtract numbers from.

Comment: it is a datatable yes. i am only parsing one column though. and from that column i want to subtract specific numbers with c#

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: No but the results of the query are.

Comment: Can you show *anything* relating to the existing query / data load? there's a *ton* of ways that could be done, so we're kinda blind here

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. keep your existing query; after you have loaded the data, iterate over the rows and manually subtract from the values
2. change your query to subtract when querying

I'd probably suggest the 1st; this sounds like a view related thing, *and* it allows more flexibility (allowing different deltas per row, for example). Since you don't show how you're currently querying and loading the data, I can't really advise further.

Comment: SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(geom, 32633)) FROM "database"; 

This is my query

Comment: @GeorgeMasterson great; now since I'm leaning towards the 1st option, that's the one bit of code we need to leave alone; so: what are you *doing* with that query? you're presumably loading into some kind of model - can we see some of that?

Comment: @GeorgeMasterson note: I'm not familiar with `ST_AsGeoJSON`, but presumably it returns JSON - in which case you're presumably deserializing this somewhere?

Comment: Yes that is correct, i am parsing all these to unity, so i can see the database results there. 
There is this in Unity: 

public class script : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () {
        script.Manager dm = new script.Manager();
        List<List<string>> GeomAsGeoJSON = dm.Test();
       
        foreach (var col in GeomAsGeoJSON)
           foreach (var row in col) 
                Debug.Log("Result => " + row);



    }

And here is where i want to subtract the number i want

Comment: @GeorgeMasterson but... those are just strings; you can't subtract a number from a string. So *first* you need to *process* the strings - presumably you have some object model that matches whatever the json is in those? But since the strings are going to be things like `{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-89.734634999999997,31.492072000000000],
[-89.734955999999997,31.492237999999997]]]}` or `{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]}` - I'm *very* unclear what you expect to "subtract", and what that would *mean*

Comment: using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    int num_cols = reader.FieldCount;
                    if (resultTable.Count != num_cols)
                    {
                        resultTable.Clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < num_cols; i++)
                            resultTable.Add(new List<string>());
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < num_cols; i++)
                        resultTable[i].Add(reader[i].ToString());

Comment: @GeorgeMasterson again, that just reads the strings; you're going to have to *deserialize* the json strings to be able to manipulate the internals

Comment: i do not know what else to tell this is all the code i have so far

Comment: @GeorgeMasterson again: you're going to have to parse the geo json items into a sensible model and *then* worry about tweaking the numbers

Answer (score -1):

Your sql would really help, but if its something like:

select myCol1, myCol2, myCol3 
from myTable
where
...

Then you could try:

select (myCol1-50),(myCol2-50),(myCol3-50)
from myTable
where
...

Comment: Yes but i need to do this in C#

Answer (score -1):

Since we can not use the * for this query

First, you identify the column from which you want to subtract and then fire query

```
select (Col1-50),(Col2-50),(Col3-50),(col4 -non integer column as it is) 
from  TableName
where condition;
```

Comment: it appears (comments) that the data being queried is actually complex opaque text (via `ST_AsGeoJSON`) - I don't think doing this SQL side is going to be viable - or certainly not *convenient*

Comment: It is not, i tried it already and this cannot be done within C# it is only possible in PostgreSQL